# Does the Ruby core reference ever explain the method lookup path?

Tags: ruby

I found an [excerpt](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/the-ruby-programming/9780596516178/ch07s08.html) from *The Ruby Programming Language* by David Flanagan and Yukihiro Matsumoto that listed the basic of method lookup:

> When Ruby evaluates a method invocation expression, it must first figure out which method is to be invoked. The process for doing this is called method lookup or method name resolution. For the method invocation expression o.m, Ruby performs name resolution with the following steps:
>
> 1. First, it checks the eigenclass of o for singleton methods named m.
> 2. If no method m is found in the eigenclass, Ruby searches the class of o for an instance method named m.
> 3. If no method m is found in the class, Ruby searches the instance methods of any modules included by the class of o. If that class includes more than one module, then they are searched in the reverse of the order in which they were included. That is, the most recently included module is searched first.
> 4. If no instance method m is found in the class of o or in its modules, then the search moves up the inheritance hierarchy to the superclass. Steps 2 and 3 are repeated for each class in the inheritance hierarchy until each ancestor class and its included modules have been searched.
> 5. If no method named m is found after completing the search, then a method named method_missing is invoked instead. In order to find an appropriate definition of this method, the name resolution algorithm starts over at step 1. The Kernel module provides a default implementation of method_missing, so this second pass of name resolution is guaranteed to succeed. The method_missing method is covered in more detail in Handling Undefined Methods.

This concept is also discussed in *The Well-Grounded Rubyist 2nd Edition* by David Black in section 13.1.3 page 394 *Singleton classes on the the method-lookup path*.

I've found questions on Stack overflow that can benefit from answers that reference the method lookup path. I started wondering if there is any official documentation on the method lookup path.

I searched http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html for "path" and "lookup" but didn't find anything.

Using the site's search functionality for ["method lookup"](http://ruby-doc.com/search.html?cx=011815814100681837392%3Awnccv6st5qk&q=method+lookup&sa=Search&cof=FORID%3A9) turns up a bunch of helpful Gists on GitHub but no official documentation.

- Does the Ruby core reference ever explain the method lookup path?
- Where is it documented?

Comment: The search doesn't find the section named [**Method Lookup**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup)?

Comment: Good to know, @muistooshort.

Comment: @muistooshort if you put together a quote and the link mentioned will accept the answer, would also love to know how you found that section. Did you use search? Did you know to use that section? What about methods stored in singleton classes? The singleton class doesn't seem to be mentioned.

Comment: I dislike the explanations you quoted, BTW. They make Ruby sound much more complicated than it actually is. The *real* method lookup algorithm (ignoring `Module#prepend`, which indeed *does* complicate matters but isn't even mentioned in the OP's sources), is much simpler: Follow the `class` pointer of the object. If the method is there, execute it. If not, follow the `superclass` pointer. Repeat from step 2. That's it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What do you mean by class pointer? If you ask an object about it's class then it won't respond with the singleton class, which is first in the method lookup. Also, what do you mean by superclass? Superclass doesn't take into account an included module via `Module#include` which is a common way to put methods in the lookup path. Where did you learn that the only thing one needs to do is follow the class and superclass pointer? I've never seen that approach to the method lookup mentioned. The point of the question is to find actual documentation describing the method lookup process.

Comment: @mbigras: "What do you mean by class pointer?" – I mean the pointer (or reference or field or whatever you want to call it) which points to the class of the object, usually its singleton class. "If you ask an object about it's class then it won't respond with the singleton class, which is first in the method lookup." – That's because the `Object#class` method does not return the class pointer, it returns the first non-singleton, non-include class, i.e. the first non-virtual class (as YARV puts it, although I don't like it, since *virtual class* already has a completely different meaning in OO)

Comment: "Also, what do you mean by superclass? Superclass doesn't take into account an included module via `Module#include` which is a common way to put methods in the lookup path." – Of course it does. What does `C.include(M)` do? It creates an *include class* `M'` whose method table pointer, constant table pointer, class variable table pointer, and instance variable table pointer point to `M`'s method table, constant table, class variable table, and instance variable table and makes the superclass of `C` the superclass of `M'`, then makes `M'` the superclass of `C`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag but that's not how the lookup works in terms of _Ruby code_. Sure the VM is creating all of that structure behind the scenes to make the lookup simple but if you ask _Ruby_, `C.superclass` is not `M'` or anything to do with `M`.

Comment: @Max: If that's not how the lookup works in terms of Ruby code, then how *does* it happen? In my Ruby code, methods in included modules override methods in the including class, which can be exactly explained by the module becoming the superclass. If you mean that it cannot be explained in terms of Ruby code, then you are of course right: method lookup is part of the semantics of Ruby code, in other words, it is part of what it means to be Ruby code; *of course*, this is impossible to explain from *within* Ruby since the semantics of Ruby come from *outside* Ruby.

Comment: "`C.superclass` is not `M'` or anything to do with `M`" – That's because `Class#superclass` does not return the superclass pointer, but skips over include classes and singleton classes until if finds a non-virtual class.

Comment: If you want the "most official" source, that would probably be section 13.3.4 of the ISO Ruby Language Specification, but that also uses entities that are not accessible from Ruby in its specification. It is simply impossible to describe the method lookup algorithm of Ruby from within Ruby, since without the method lookup algorithm, *there is no Ruby*. [Note: it is of course possible to *express* the method lookup algorithm *in* Ruby, in fact, converting either my description or the one from the ISO spec is rather trivial. But that is not the same thing as describing it from within Ruby.]

Comment: @JörgWMittag It sounds like you've formed a clear idea in your mind about how the method lookup process works, so clear that you find the process trivial. The goal of the question is to find actual official documentation (not your interpretation of the actual documentation) to help others figure out the process also. The tip about ISO Ruby Language Specification helps achieve goal of the question, your opinion that the process is trivial does not.

Comment: @mbigras: Method lookup is the single most often executed operation in an object-oriented system. It *must* be trivial, otherwise, the system would be unusably slow. That's why "c = obj.__class__; until m = c.__methods__[method] do c = c.superclass done; execute m" was chosen to implement method lookup in a trivial manner and push the complexity into operations that are executed seldomly, such as `Object#class`, `Class#superclass`, `Module#ancestors`, and `Module#include`.